# Prove that the following set is an embedded submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Let $\mathbb{R}$ act in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $\lambda \cdot (x,y) := (x + \lambda, y), \ \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. If we define an equivalence relation $\sim$ by
$$(x,y) \sim (x',y') \iff (x,y) = \lambda\cdot(x',y'), \ \text{for some } \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$$
i.e., we have $(x,y) \sim (x',y')$ iff $x = x' + \lambda$ and $y = y'$, for some $\lambda$. Now, we may define
\begin{align}
R & = \{((x,y), (x',y')) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 : (x,y) \sim (x',y')\} \\ & \cong \{((x,y), (x + \lambda, y) ) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2: \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}.
\end{align}
How can I show that $R$ is actually an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2$?

I've noticed that this problem is suspiciously similar to Example 10.3 of Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds (2nd edition), although (seemingly) harder.

**Edit**: Moreover, I know that:

- The equivalence classes are the lines parallel to the $x$ axis. Indeed, if $(x,y) \sim (x',y')$, then $y' = y$ and $x' = x + \lambda$, for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, and thus $(x',y')$ lies in such a line. The other way around is analogous.
- The main tool I use to show that some subset $S$ of a manifold $M$ is an embedded submanifold is to show that $S$ can be seen as a preimage of some regular value under some smooth map $f$, which is pretty much what I've tried on this particular problem. I did not get far with it, as I didn't find any map $f$ that did the job. I still suspect this strategy will work on this question, though.

Comment: I don’t have Lee’s book to compare. But start by describing $R$ geometrically. What *are* the equivalence classes?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I've answered both your questions via an Edit on the post. Sorry for taking so long.

Comment: Note that $(x_1, y_1) \sim (x_2, y_2)$ iff $y_1 = y_2$. Can you find a function $f : \mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ so that $f^{-1}(0) = R$?

Comment: Ah, yes. I think I got it: A map $f$ that tells the angle between $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ (like $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f((x,y),(x',y')) := \displaystyle{\operatorname{arccos}\left( \frac{(x,y) \cdot (x',y')}{||(x,y)||\ ||x',y'||} \right)}$) may do the job, as $f^{-1}(0) = R$.